# How to Keep dtype('o') in df instead of bool

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I'm trying to combine 5 columns in my dataframe into one column that has string values such as 'A' or 'B'. I've converted the 1's into A, B, C ....

My current columns look like this

```
   A B C D E 
1  A
2      C
3  A
4
5        D
6
7          E
8
9          E
10  B
```

And I want my column to look like this

```
  Type
1  A
2  C
3  A
4
5  D
6
7  E
8
9  E
10 B
```

However, it's returning True and False instead of A,B,C..

My code is listed below

```
dfparsed_A = dfparsed_groupby[(dfparsed_groupby['A'] == 1)]
dfparsed_B = dfparsed_groupby[(dfparsed_groupby['B'] == 1)]
dfparsed_C = dfparsed_groupby[(dfparsed_groupby['C'] == 1)]
dfparsed_D = dfparsed_groupby[(dfparsed_groupby['D'] == 1)]
dfparsed_E = dfparsed_groupby[(dfparsed_groupby['E'] == 1)]

dfparsed_['A'] = dfparsed_groupby['A'].astype(str).replace('1', 'A')
dfparsed_['B'] = dfparsed_groupby['B'].astype(str).replace('1', 'B')
dfparsed_['C'] = dfparsed_groupby['C'].astype(str).replace('1', 'C')
dfparsed_['D'] = dfparsed_groupby['D'].astype(str).replace('1', 'D')
dfparsed_['E'] = dfparsed_groupby['E'].astype(str).replace('1', 'E')

dfparsed2=[(dfparsed_groupby['A'] == 'A') | (dfparsed_groupby['B'] == 'B') | (dfparsed_groupby['C'] == 'C') |(dfparsed_groupby['D'] == 'D') | (dfparsed_groupby['E'] == 'E') ] 

print(dfparsed2)
```

```
...
 1203     True
 5368     True
 5644    False
 1089     True
 6488     True
 5651     True
 6485     True
 6237     True
 7632     True
 7637     True
 5635    False
 7445     True
 7484     True
 7492     True
 7638     True
 Length: 6362, dtype: bool]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#if necessary
#df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df['Type'] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
print (df)
      A    B    C    D    E Type
1     A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    A
2   NaN  NaN    C  NaN  NaN    C
3     A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    A
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN    D  NaN    D
6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    E    E
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    E    E
10  NaN    B  NaN  NaN  NaN    B
```

If there is only one non NaN value of all NaNs values per rows:

```
mask = df == 1
df['Type'] = mask.dot(df.columns)
print (df)
      A    B    C    D    E Type
1     1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    A
2   NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN    C
3     1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    A
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     
5   NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN    D
6   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1    E
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN     
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1    E
10  NaN    1  NaN  NaN  NaN    B
```